# How to get all documents(including data) in String array from a collection in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all `itemName` of all documents in a String `array`,
further I want to perform searching on that array, how could I achieve my task? Please help me. Thanx.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge5x2.png

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). If you have a hard time making this work for your use-case, edit your question to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sir , i changed my description, please read it and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get all itemName of all documents in a string array

To get all item names within all documents, you need to create a reference and use a `get()` call, like in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference offersDataRef = rootRef.collection("MartWayDB").document("Offers")
    .collection("OffersData");
offersDataRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String[] array = new String[task.getResult().size()];
            int count = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String itemName = document.getString("itemName");
                array[count] = itemName;
                Log.d(TAG, itemName);
                count++;
            }

            //Do what you need to do with your array
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx dear, this saves my lot of time, Further i'll ask more questions to you.

Comment: can you help me, how to searching in this array, Actually i'm working on ecomerce  android app, in which i'm trying to search the product by name from this array, this search should be ignoring case sensitivity, how could i achieve my task, please guide me.

Comment: This sounds as another issue, which should be considered another question. So in order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question so me and other Firebase developers can help you.